# The difference and use of strings and string arrays?

Tags: vb6

Okay, so for all i know a string is basically an array of characters. So why would there be string arrays in VB? And what differences are between them?

Just the basics, the way they operate that's what i'm interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you need to store a list of names, it might be 100 names, or 200 names.. it depends from case to case.. what will u do?

String array can solve such case

Try this:

```
Dim Names() As String
ReDim Names(3) As String
Names(0) = "First"
Names(1) = "Second"
Names(2) = "Third"
Names(3) = "Fourth"
Dim l As Long
For l = LBound(Names) To UBound(Names)
    MsgBox Names(l)
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

At times it is very useful to think of a String as an array of characters.  It can also be useful to think of it as an array of bytes at times too - and this is of course not the same thing at all.

See [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) for better understanding of the differences between bytes and the characters held by Strings (UTF-16LE) as well as other character encodings commonly used.

But all of that aside, a String is really a higher level abstraction that you should not think of as an array of any kind.

After all, by that sort of logic an Integer or Long is an array as well.

So considering that a String is meant to be viewed as a primitive scalar value type the purpose of String arrays should be pretty clear.  Arrays of Strings have pretty much the same sorts of uses as arrays of any other data type.

The fact that you have operations you can perform on Strings that root around inside them (substring operations) isn't much different conceptually than the operations that operate on the data inside any other simple type.